# Listview getItemAt returns null

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to move items to reorder them inside a `listview` with `largeImage style.`
The problems exists in the `getItemAt(x, y)` method inside `dragdrop` because this method always returns null **only if the** `dragDrop` **isn't performed exactly over an existing item** (**Usually I drop between two items, it is more intuitive imo**).

```
private void lvPictures_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = lvPictures.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    ListViewItem MovetoNewPosition = lvPictures.GetItemAt(p.X, p.Y);
    //MovetoNewPosition is null
}
```

So the point is, how does one get the closest item if the `dragDrop` is performed between two items - and not over one?

---

The answer pointed me into the correct direction, this is how I did implement the "find nearest" method: (might not be perfect but it works for now)

```
ListViewItem itemToBeMoved = (e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)) as ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)[0];
ListViewItem itemToBeMovedClone = (ListViewItem)itemToBeMoved.Clone();

ListViewItem itemInDropPosition = listView.GetItemAt(p.X, p.Y);
if (itemInDropPosition == null)
{
    ListViewItem leftItem = listView.FindNearestItem(SearchDirectionHint.Left, p);
    ListViewItem rightItem = listView.FindNearestItem(SearchDirectionHint.Right, p);
    if (leftItem == null && rightItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (leftItem == null)
    {
        itemInDropPosition = rightItem;
    }
    else if (rightItem == null)
    {
        itemInDropPosition = leftItem;
    }
    else
    {
    //PGM: appens that if you move to the right or to the left, between two items, the left item (if moving to the right) or the right item (if moving to the left) is wrong, because it select not the first one, but the second
        if (rightItem.Index - leftItem.Index > 1 && leftItem.Index < itemToBeMoved.Index && rightItem.Index <= itemToBeMoved.Index)
        {
            //we are moving to the left
            rightItem = listView.Items[rightItem.Index - 1];
        }
        else if (rightItem.Index - leftItem.Index > 1 && leftItem.Index >= itemToBeMoved.Index && rightItem.Index > itemToBeMoved.Index)
        {
            //we are moving to the right
            leftItem = listView.Items[leftItem.Index + 1];
        }
        else if (rightItem.Index - leftItem.Index > 1)
        {
            //significa che è stato spostato sul posto e non va mosso
            return;
        }
        if (Math.Abs(p.X - leftItem.Position.X) < Math.Abs(p.X - rightItem.Position.X))
        {
            itemInDropPosition = leftItem;
        }
        else
        {
            itemInDropPosition = rightItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [ListView.FindNearestItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.findnearestitem?view=netframework-4.7.2) work better for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the assist! I added in question how I did implement your solution into the code, since FindNearestItem doesn't return the actual nearest but the nearest in the direction you tell it to look for :)